# How can I align some text vertically in the middle of an HTML image?

Tags: css

I have this:
http://jsfiddle.net/8KWtH/

I would like to move the > so it is in the middle vertically of the two images.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your images to have `vertical-align:middle;` but that will make the > **start** from the middle. so it will still go up a little.
example: http://jsfiddle.net/8KWtH/14/

---

Applying the vertical align to the span as well makes it perfect.
example: http://jsfiddle.net/8KWtH/22/

Comment: just applied this a second ago myself locally then saw your answer when I refreshed my own.

Answer (score 2):

Use `line-height` to accomplish this:

```
<span style="font-size: 34px;line-height: 79px;"> &gt; </span>
```

**EDIT:**
Because of the nature of the images, you need to use `vertical-align` to accomplish this:

```
<div style="float: left;">
<img src="http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-2.jpg" style="width: 60px; height: 79px;vertical-align: middle;">
<span style="font-size: 34px;"> &gt; </span>
<img src="http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-2.jpg" style="width: 60px; height: 79px;vertical-align: middle;">
</div>
```

Comment: @Karem - I also just tried this and for some reason I see it is not working, though I have used this technique many times before.

Comment: thank you for replying and answering well, fastly after I wrote my last comment I saw Gaby's answer that worked fine, therefore I accept Gaby's. Although I upvoted for a good answer.

Comment: @Karem: absolutely. I also upvoted his answer. He put the correct one up first IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by using the following instead of >.

```
&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I whipped out something [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8KWtH/16/)

From what I can see it is basically a variation on the other answers but it gets the job done